# matlab can't show image after drawing a shape using shapeInserter

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-cvst

i'm trying to use shapeInserter as shown [here](http://www.mathworks.it/help/vision/ref/vision.shapeinserter-class.html), but when i use imshow i get this error:

```
Error using imageDisplayValidateParams>validateCData (line 126)
RGB images must be uint8, uint16, single, or double.

Error in imageDisplayValidateParams (line 27)
common_args.CData = validateCData(common_args.CData,image_type);

Error in imageDisplayParseInputs (line 78)
common_args = imageDisplayValidateParams(common_args);

Error in imshow (line 219)
[common_args,specific_args] = ...

Error in myScript (line 35)
imshow(img1);
```

here is my code:

```
shapeInserter = vision.ShapeInserter('Shape','Rectangles','BorderColor','Custom', 'CustomBorderColor', uint8([255 0 0]));
rect = int32([x, y, 10, 10]);
rgb = repmat(img, [1, 1, 3]);
img1 = step(shapeInserter, rgb, rect);
imshow(img1);
```

where `img` is a grayscale image i loaded before.

Comment: I tried you code and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of `img`?  It appears that it is not one of the types allowed by `imshow`: uint8, uint16, single, or double. If that's the case, you should convert it to one of those types.

If you have a recent version of MATLAB, try using the `insertShape` function, which has a simpler interface.

Comment: the type of `img` is `int16` and `imshow` works fine! but it doesn't work when i try to show `rgb` or `img1` (both are `int16`). i have the same problem using `insertShape`.

Comment: Well, it looks like imshow displays a grayscale int16 image, but throws an error for an rgb int16 image.  The only thing you can do at this point is use a different data type.